# Automatically expanded rows and columns

Tags: powershell, user-interface, datagridview, rows

I am using code to open and view an XML file in datagridview, but the rows and columns are not already open like they are in excel.

I have been searching the internet for answers on how to have the data already presented like it would be in excel, but have not been able to find how to do this.

```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') 
[Void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
[Void][System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#Open File Dialog
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory){   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "XML (*.xml)| *.xml"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
} 

#Save File Dialog
Function Save-FileName($initialDirectory){   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "XML (*.xml)| *.xml"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
} 

#Create Form Functions
function Create-Form {
#       Draw Form
    $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form1.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(725,400)
    $form1.Text = "XML to DataGrid Editor" 
    $form1.Name = "form1" 
    $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = 5
#       Draw DataGrid
    $dataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
    $dataGrid1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,338)
    $dataGrid1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (13,13)
    $dataGrid1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
    $dataGrid1.HeaderForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,0,0,0) 
    $dataGrid1.Name = "dataGrid1" 
    $dataGrid1.DataMember = "" 
    $dataGrid1.TabIndex = 0 
    $form1.Controls.Add($dataGrid1) 
#       Draw Open xml Configuration Button
    $button_openxml = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_openxml.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,25)
    $button_openxml.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,365)
    $button_openxml.Text = "Open XML Document"
    $button_openxml.Add_Click({
        $xml_networkschema = Get-FileName
#           Bind Data to DataGrid
        $ds = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
        $ds.ReadXml($xml_networkschema)
        $dataGrid1.DataSource = $ds
    })
    $form1.Controls.Add($button_openxml)
#       Save xml Configuration Button
    $button_savexml = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_savexml.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,25)
    $button_savexml.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(170,365)
    $button_savexml.Text = "Save XML Document"
    $button_savexml.enabled = "false"
    $button_savexml.Add_Click({
        $dbm_savenetworkschema = Save-FileName
        $dataGrid1.DataSource.writexml($dbm_savenetworkschema)
    })
    $form1.Controls.Add($button_savexml)
    $form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null 
}

Create-Form
```

---

[what the display should like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfR7T.png)

Comment: Hi. Could you please provide examples with how you want the data to be displayed? There are many different ways to present data in Excel. You could attach screenshots of how the data looks and how you would like it to look, and that would make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: what i am trying to do is to pull the areas, with their associated details from the xml, and display it like a table in excel.  *see below*                                                           name lat                 long                alt a r g b nofill description
area1 0.123456786 0.891234567 0 255 255 255 115 TRUE 
area1 0.234567891 0.789123456 0 255 255 255 115 TRUE 
area1 0.345678912 0.678912345 0 255 255 255 115 TRUE 
area1 0.456789123 0.567891234 0 255 255 255 115 TRUE

Comment: Do not add hard to read code/information into comments, instead [edit] your question to contain that, if necessary read the [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)